# How to transform data in R

Tags: r

I have this kind of data....

```
Id             Name                   gid    
GO:0019992  diacylglycerol binding  23025    
GO:0019992  diacylglycerol binding  10497    
GO:0045703  ketoreductase activity  8644    
GO:0016519  gastric inhibitory peptide receptor activity    2696    
GO:0035174  histone serine kinase activity  5562    
GO:0035174  histone serine kinase activity  5563    
GO:0035174  histone serine kinase activity  6795    
GO:0030298  receptor signaling protein tyrosine kinase activator activity   6352   
GO:0030292  protein tyrosine kinase inhibitor activity  11116   
GO:0030292  protein tyrosine kinase inhibitor activity  10399
```

I have to change this into

```
GO:0019992  diacylglycerol binding  23025 10497    
GO:0045703  ketoreductase activity  8644    
GO:0016519  gastric inhibitory peptide receptor activity    2696    
GO:0035174  histone serine kinase activity  5562 5563 472 6790 9212 6795    
GO:0035175  histone kinase activity (H3-S10 specific)   7443    
GO:0030298  receptor signaling protein tyrosine kinase activator activity   6352    
GO:0030292  protein tyrosine kinase inhibitor activity  11116 10399
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: @Downvoter: Downvoting without a comment is bad form. This is exceptionally true on a new users first question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get there with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df) # where df is your table of GO terms
dt <- dt[,list(gids=paste(gid, collapse=" ")), by=list(Id, Name)]
```

Comment: You don't need the full `dt <- as.data.table(df)` statement. Just `setDT(df)` is enough to convert to `data.table` format.

Comment: Thanks ! Scott ... It works

Comment: Thanks @Jaap I didn't know about `setDT`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data.frame is named `df`

Base:

```
new_var <- unlist(
  lapply(
    split(df,f = df$Name), 
    function(x) paste0(x$gid, collapse= " ")
  )
)
df <- df[unique(df[,1:2]),]
df$new_var <- new_var
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, here's another way using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
     group_by(Id, Name) %>% 
     summarise(gids = paste(gid, collapse = " "))
```